# characteristic method for a pde

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, partial-differential-equations, characteristics

I have the following PDE:
\begin{align}
\frac{d}{dt}u(t,r)&=\alpha(r-\beta)\frac{d}{dr}u(t,r)+\alpha u(t,r)\\
u(0,r)=&u_0(r)
\end{align}

where $r\in [0,1]$ and $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are fixed constants in $[0,1]$.

I would like to solve this equation with the characteristic's method.

If my computations are correct the equations of the characeristics are given by
\begin{align}
&\frac{dt}{ds}=-1,\\
&\frac{dr}{ds}=\alpha({r-\beta})
\end{align}
while the equation along the characteristics is
\begin{align}
\frac{du}{ds}=-\alpha u
\end{align}
and consequently the total solution is given by $u(t,r)=u_0((r-\beta)e^{\alpha t})+\beta)e^{\alpha  t}$.

My problem is that, under the hypotesis $u_0(r)\in[0,1]$ I should have $u(t,r)\in[0,1]$ for every $t\geq 0$, but according to the solution that I get, it doesen't seem to be in this way. There is something wrong in my argument?

Could someone help me?

Comment: You are totally right, I modified the text! Anyway the solution is $u(s)=u_0e^{-\alpha s}$ but $s=-t$ and this means that the sign in the exponential is positive... Am I wrong?

Comment: Your result $u(t,r)=u_0(r-\beta(1-e^{-\alpha t}))e^{\alpha  t}$ is not correct. But you have not edited the intermediate steps. So, it is impossible to say where exactly is the mistake. May be, comparing to my answer will allow you so find what is wrong in your argument. Anyways, it is not recommended to simply write "Consequently the total solution is given by … '' : the missing steps are not so simple.

Answer (score 1):

$$\frac{d}{dt}u(t,r)-\alpha(r-\beta)\frac{d}{dr}u(t,r)=\alpha u(t,r)$$
$$\frac{dt}{1}=\frac{dr}{\alpha(\beta-r)}=\frac{du}{\alpha u}=-ds$$
It doesn't mater the coefficient of the parameter $s$. I put $-1$ to be consistent with the meaning of $s$ in your notations. So, your characteristic ODEs are consistent with mine. Your mistake is later. Compare your further calculus with the following :

First characteristic curves, from $\quad \frac{dt}{1}=\frac{du}{\alpha u}$
$$u e^{-\alpha t}=c_1$$
Second characteristic curves, from $\quad \frac{dt}{1}=\frac{dr}{\alpha(\beta-r)}$
$$(r-\beta)e^{\alpha t}=c_2$$
The general solution on implicit form is $\quad u e^{-\alpha t}=F\left((r-\beta)e^{\alpha t} \right)\quad$ where $F$ is an arbitrary function.

The general solution on explicit form is :
$$u(r,t)=e^{\alpha t}F\left((r-\beta)e^{\alpha t} \right)$$
Condition :

$u(0,r)=u_0(r)=e^{\alpha 0}F\left((r-\beta)e^{\alpha 0} \right)=F\left((r-\beta) \right)$

Let $x=r-\beta$. $\quad r=x+\beta\quad;\quad u_0(r)=u_0(x+\beta)=F(x).$
$$F(x)=u_0(x+\beta)$$

Now, the function $F(x)$ is determined. We put it into the above general solution where $x=(r-\beta)e^{\alpha t}\quad$  thus $\quad F(x)=u_0(x+\beta)=u_0\left((r-\beta)e^{\alpha t}+\beta \right)$.

$$u(r,t)=e^{\alpha t}u_0\left((r-\beta)e^{\alpha t}+\beta \right)$$

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I checked my computation and I agree that the final solution is the one that you wrote : $u(r,t)=e^{\alpha t}u_0((r-\beta)e^{\alpha t}+\beta)$.

Comment: I made a mistake in my computations. Anyway what bother me is the fact that $u(r,t)$ can be larger then $1$ even if the initial datum $u(r)\in [0,1]$ and this shouldn't happen (because of the nature of my problem, the solution represent a quantity which is always in [0,1], so I have the doubt that t he initial PDE is wrong). Do you agree that if the solution is the one you found and $\alpha$ is a positive parameter, the solution is exploding as $t\to +\infty$? Right?

Comment: All depends on the function $u_0(r)$ which is not explicit in the wording of the question. For example, if $u_0(r)=\exp(-r^2)$  the solution is far to exploding.

Comment: No, sorry I didn't modified the text yet.... I will do it now... But I totally agree with the solution that you have written...

Comment: OK. but exploding or not depends on $u_0(r)$.

Comment: Yes... Actually the only condition that I have over $u_0(r)$ is that $u_0(r)\in [0,1]$ and $\int_0^1u_0(r)dr=1$ and I think that these conditions are not enough to prove that the solution is always confined in $[0,1]$. I guess The PDE is wrong.

Comment: If the PDE is wrong, that's another story. Good bye and good luck.